# Gerund or Infinitives?

Tags: participles, gerund-vs-infinitive

How can I grammatically explain gerund "seeking" in this sentence? Can I use "to seek" instead?

> *I am Sharron Biggs, CEO and founder of BiggsGraphics. I recently came across your advertisement **seeking** the partnership of a graphic design company for a number of your projects.*

Comment: No, you can't. An infinitival clause would be a relative one, but that wouldn't work here since non-_wh_ infinitival relatives have a modal meaning similar to that expressed by "can" or "should", which would make no sense here. Note, though, that you could replace it with a finite relative clause, e.g. "I recently came across your advertisement [that seeks the partnership of a graphic design company for a number of your projects].

Comment: You asked Colin about the possibility of "We're conducting a campaign [to increase sales]". Yes, this is fine, but it has nothing to do with nouns. It's a purpose adjunct consisting of an infinitival clause modifying "campaign".

Comment: Is "seek" an action verb used for people in passive voice? Can "advertisement" go with "seek"?

Comment: You could say *I recently came across your advertisement* ***that you are using to seek*** *the partnership of a graphic designer*.

Answer (score 1):

"Seeking" is not a gerund there, but a participle, the head of the postposed adjectival (participial) clause "seeking the partnership of a graphic design company for a number of your projects", which modifies "advertisement".

Neither a gerund nor an infinitive would make sense there, as they both fulfil the role of a noun phrase.

Comment: Thank you. How about this sentence? "We're conducting a campaign to increase sales". Does "to increase" function as a noun?

Comment: @AnhLe: I wondered whether to mention that special case, and decided not to. Normally a "to" infinitive, like a gerund, heads a clause that functions as a noun phrase. But an infinitive clause can also be used as an adjectival or adverbial clause of purpose. Here "to increase sales" is adjectival.

Comment: @ColinFine The infinitival "to increase sales" is strictly speaking ambiguous. It could either be a purpose adjunct as in "We're conducting a campaign (in order) to increase sales, or a complement of the noun "campaign". Infinitival relatives (your 'adjectival') have a modal meaning similar to that expressed by "can" or "should", but I don't think that meaning would make much sense here.

Comment: @BillJ: true; I missed the alternative parse (though in this case there's little difference in meaning).